# Is there a way to have the option create table in the toolbar of p-editor element from primeNg?

Tags: angular, html-table, editor, primeng, quill

I'm using primeNg library in my Angular Project (14.2.0).
One of the components uses p-editor to create Templates, it has the options I need it to have, except "create table".

```
          <p-editor
            id="campo_texto"
            name="texto"
            formControlName="texto"
          >
            <p-header>
              <span class="ql-formats">
                <select class="ql-size">
                  <option value="small">Small</option>
                  <option selected></option>
                  <option value="large">Large</option>
                  <option value="huge">Huge</option>
                </select>
              </span>
              <span class="ql-formats">
                <button class="ql-bold" aria-label="Bold"></button>
                <button class="ql-italic" aria-label="Italic"></button>
                <button class="ql-underline" aria-label="Underline"></button>
                <button class="ql-strike" aria-label="Strike"></button>
              </span>
              <span class="ql-formats">
                <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
                <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
                <select title="Text Alignment" class="ql-align">
                  <option selected>Left</option>
                  <option value="center" label="Center"></option>
                  <option value="right" label="Right"></option>
                  <option value="justify" label="Justify"></option>
                </select>
              </span>
            </p-header>
          </p-editor>
```

Is there a way to have the option create table in the toolbar of p-editor element from primeNg?
I searched for it for a while in primeNG editor documentation and in Quill and couldn't find.

I tried to install some modules for tables that I found in internet that promised to works, but didn't. I just need a button in the toolbar that could created a simple table inside the editor for the users.

Comment: Hey are you looking to create an Excel like table from your RTF (Quill) data?

Comment: Just a normal table as tinyMCE and CKEditor have.

Comment: So, you have some raw text in an RTF editor and you would like to generate an HTML table from the text data.  Are you supplying a template for the data? How are you defining columns and rows?

Comment: I searched for a native way in this component to create the tables and I coudn't find, so, after making the question, I created a function that could write the tags HTML in the raw text of the p-editor: <table>,<th> and <tr>.
For a moment I though it would work, but I noticed that the component was subscribing the HTML tags of the function for the paragrath tab <p>, ignoring.